# How to get ID in for NSManagedObjectID or NSString stringWithFormat and individual passage ID in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need passage-id in for-loop, I am stuck in this from last week.

I try to get value from `NSManagedObjectID` or `objectAtIndex` but I am not able to figure out some how I am new in iOS development.

thanks in advance please any one help.

```
    SearchRuleTableItem* searchTableItem = ((SearchRuleTableItem*) object);
    NSString *passageIdAll;
    passageIdAll = @"";
    NSLog(@"SEARCH RULE TABLE ITEM = %@",searchTableItem);
    if (searchTableItem.ruleId) {
        NSLog(@"SEARCH TABEL ITEM RULE ID = %@",searchTableItem.ruleId );
        AppDelegate_Shared* delegate = (AppDelegate_Shared *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];          
       for (int icount = 0; icount<[searchTableItem.passageArray count]; icount++) {
            //  NSArray * passageId = [searchTableItem.passageArray objectsAtIndexes:icount];
            //  NSLog(@"NSManagedObjectID = %@",passageId);
            //  NSManagedObject* passageId = (NSManagedObject*)[searchTableItem.passageArray objectsAtIndexes:0];
                NSManagedObjectID* passageId = (NSManagedObjectID *)[searchTableItem.passageArray objectAtIndex:passageId];

            //  NSManagedObjectID * moID = [passageId objectID];
            //  NSMutableString *postString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:searchTableItem.passageArray];

            //  NSLog(@"NSManagedObjectID moID = %@",postString);
            //  NSString * PA =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[searchTableItem.passageArray objectsAtIndexes:icount]];

            NSString* passageIdStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[searchTableItem.passageArray objectAtIndex:icount]];                
            passageIdAll = [[passageIdAll stringByAppendingString:@"|"] stringByAppendingString: passageIdStr];
            NSLog(@"PASSAGE ID - 2 = %@",passageIdAll);
            //NSLog(@"PASSAGE ID = %@",passageIdStr);
        }
        Section* theSection = (Section*) [delegate.managedObjectContext objectWithID:searchTableItem.ruleId];
           // NSLog(@"SECTION DEFINED = %@",theSection);
        if (searchTableItem.passageId && theSection) {
            Passage* passage = (Passage*)[delegate.managedObjectContext objectWithID:searchTableItem.passageId];
            //Passage* passage = (Passage*)[delegate.managedObjectContext objectWithID:passageId];
            if (passage) {
                NSLog(@"teset Passage -, %@", passage.id);
                [delegate performSelector:@selector(showContentWithData:)
                       withObject:@{@"sectionId": theSection.id, @"passageId": passage.id, @"allPasageId": passageIdAll}
                              afterDelay:0.75];
            }
        }            
    }
```

her is console part

> 2015-07-01 11:35:25.635 rulebook[21297:607] SEARCH RULE TABLE ITEM =
>
> 2015-07-01 11:35:25.637 rulebook[21297:607] SEARCH TABEL ITEM RULE ID = 0x789c7020
>
> 2015-07-01 11:35:31.553 [21297:607] PASSAGE ID - 2 = |0x789c5c00
>
> 2015-07-01 11:35:31.556 [21297:607] PASSAGE ID - 2 = |0x789c5c00 |0x787ac1d0
>
> 2015-07-01 11:35:31.559 [21297:607] PASSAGE ID - 2 = |0x789c5c00 |0x787ac1d0 |0x787d8e80
>
> 2015-07-01 11:35:31.562 [21297:607] PASSAGE ID - 2 = |0x789c5c00 |0x787ac1d0 |0x787d8e80 |0x787eae30
>
> 2015-07-01 11:35:31.564 [21297:607] PASSAGE ID - 2 = |0x789c5c00 |0x787ac1d0 |0x787d8e80 |0x787eae30 |0x78e36730
>
> 2015-07-01 11:35:31.622 [21297:607] PASSAGE ID - 2 = |0x789c5c00 |0x787ac1d0 |0x787d8e80 |0x787eae30 |0x78e36730 |0x78707ac0

for example I need passage id like below mention 421608 not like showing in above.

> 2015-07-01 11:35:31.625 [21297:607] test Passage -, 421608

Comment: @Lancelot de la Mare actuley i am just new in ios so i am trying various  thing's try and error base, can you please explain what i am doing wrong ..... thanx

Comment: @LancelotdelaMare may be its ints ... so what should i do now for this .....please help me out ...

Comment: There is **not enough information** in your question to figure out what is wrong. Is it possible that your `NSManagedObject` are temporary (i.e. not loaded)? You are also printing objects, such as `NSNumber`, instead of value. Try `NSLog(@"%d", [passage.id integerValue]);`. May I also suggest the tutorials at http://www.raywenderlich.com ?

Comment: @LancelotdelaMare i try with this NSLog but is showing only one value only id i need all id related to searchTableItem.passageArray.... i need values in side for loop so one by one i d\get the PassageId ....?